# windows.onload and setInterval still requiring manual refresh to work

Tags: javascript, setinterval, onload

Having read the threads on this topic, am still stuck.

For some reason, function 'raat' is only called when the page is reloaded manually.  How can I get the span to refresh automatically?

```
<span id="sn1"></span>
<script>
function raat() {
var sesh = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['customer_id']); ?>;
var vx = document.getElementById("sn1");
if ( sesh > 0) {
vx.innerHTML='<li><a href="J05.php" target="iframe_m">Edit Account Info</a></li>';
} else {
vx.innerHTML='';}
}; /* end raat */

window.onload=raat();    

setInterval( raat, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks all (epascarello, Rob, Mehran).  Having tried all permutations as suggested, this conditional still only switches if the page is manually refreshed.  I can t expalin it other than perhpas, as epascarelo suggests, the newly updated $_SESSION is not accessable to the recursive call of <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['customer_id']); ?>;.  In fact I did start with an AJAX / PHP approach but ws having difficulty making that work.  I could of course resort to <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" > as a last resort, but will continue to fiddle with the AJAX.  again - MANY THANKS ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling raat and assigning whatever it returns to onload

```
window.onload=raat();
```

It needs to be

```
window.onload=raat;
```

And hopefully you realize that `<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['customer_id']); ?>;` will not keep updating, the value will be the same since it is only added when the page is rendered. If you want to get info when that is updated, you will need to make an Ajax call to the server to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this also ( it looked confusing to be setting the `interval` off while the other is waiting for onload

```
window.onload= function() { 

   raat();    

   setInterval( raat, 3000);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it using `addEventListener`:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    raat();
});
```